# select two specific classes with find_all in Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, class, beautifulsoup, find

I want to use BeautifulSoup to scrape some data from a website. The data is in a table where the different table rows as 4 different classes in total.

```
<table class="timeteam">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="even"></tr>
        <tr class="even smallrow"></tr>
        <tr class="odd"></tr>
        <tr class="odd smallrow"></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The data in the rows 'even' and 'odd' belongs together. So I want to get those two rows (and the other rows as well) at the end in a Dataframe.

With find_all('tr', class_=['even', 'odd']) I also get the other rows (with smallrow). Therefore I tried the recompile function. But still the same result.

What do I need to change in my code to select only the rows with the classes 'even' and 'odd'?

Here's my code:

```
import requests
import re
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

page = request.get('https://regatta.time-team.nl/hollandia/2017/results/003.php')
soup = bs(page.content, 'html.parser')

tables = soup.find_all('table', class_='timeteam')

player_data_even = []
player_data_smallrow = []
for i in range(len(tables)):    
    for tr in tables[i].find_all('tr', class_ = re.compile(r"^(even|odd)$")):      
        player_row_even = []
        for td in tr.find_all('td'):    
            player_row_even.append(td.get_text())    
        player_data_even.append(player_row_even)
    for tr in tables[i].find_all('tr', class_=['even smallrow', 'odd smallrow']):
        player_row_smallrow = []
        for td in tr.find_all('td'):
            player_row_smallrow.append(td.get_text())
        player_data_smallrow.append(player_row_smallrow)

players_even = pd.DataFrame(player_data_even)
players_smallrow = pd.DataFrame(player_data_smallrow)
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, it seems your problem is solved. You can have all the data sequentially now. Give it a shot:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

res = requests.get("https://regatta.time-team.nl/hollandia/2017/results/003.php")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")

for table in soup.find(class_="timeteam").find_all("tr",class_=['even','odd']):
    if "smallrow" not in table.get('class'):  #this is the fix
        data = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in table]
        print(data)
```

Output you may get like:

```
['1.', 'PHO', 'Phocas 1 (p2)', '', '--', '', '--', '', '--', '', '06:39,86', '(1)', 'KF']
['2.', 'PAM', 'Pampus (p4)', '', '--', '', '--', '', '--', '', '06:45,21', '(2)', 'KF']
['3.', 'SKO', 'Skøll 1', '', '--', '', '--', '', '--', '', '06:46,23', '(3)', 'KF']
['4.', 'NJO', 'Njord (p1)', '', '--', '', '--', '', '--', '', '06:49,44', '(4)', 'KF']
['5.', 'GYA', 'Gyas (SB)', '', '--', '', '--', '', '--', '', '06:50,04', '(5)', 'KF']
['6.', 'PRO', 'Proteus 1 (p7)', '', '--', '', '--', '', '--', '', '06:50,24', '(6)', 'KF']
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Now I have to find a way to get the data in the right order and combine the data with the data from the other rows with the classes even smallrow and odd smallrow.

Comment: So yes, sequence is important;-)

Comment: Don't miss the update @Jeroen Spaans. I've got your problem solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use check if the list containing the classes have a length of one:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
content = """
  <table class="timeteam">
   <tbody>
    <tr class="even">yes</tr>
    <tr class="even smallrow">no</tr>
    <tr class="odd">yes</tr>
    <tr class="odd smallrow">no</tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
"""
s = [i.text for i in soup(content, 'html.parser').find_all('tr') if len(i['class']) == 1]
```

Output:

```
['yes', 'yes']
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I tried this option but did not get it as I wanted in my script. I got an attribute error. Bu I will look further if I can make it work